# how to display a certain subset of data on prettytable in a descending order

Tags: python, sorting, prettytable

i have a `PrettyTable` with two headers and over 500 rows, the structure is like this

```
Email Address     number of contacts
aaa@goo.com        99
aaa@foo.com        123
```

and my code:

```
  table =pt.PrettyTable(["Email Address", "Number of Contacts"])
  for n in g3.nodes():
     table.add_row([n.title(),g3.in_degree(n)])  
  table.reversesort=True
  print table.get_string(sortby="Number of Contacts")
```

i'm trying to organise the table in a descending order by sorting the number of contacts. what i actually want, is a table that displays the 20 e-mail addresses with the highest number of contacts . i dont want the rest to be on the table. with the help of some other questions on here, i could do the descending order but im stuck there and couldn't find a way of doing what i want. i've looked [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PTable/0.9.0) but couldn't find a solution either. any suggestions?

Comment: Is `PrettyTable` a must? How about using `pandas`?

Comment: yea, this is for a uni assignment and i have to use it.